Finitely generated and finitely presented
For a group, it seems fairly clear that finitely presented implies finitely generated.
But what about the converse?   Is there a finitely generated group that is not finitely presented.
(Let's say finitely presented means has a presentation where the set of generators and the set of relators are finite.)

Quoting from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group#Examples) "An example of a finitely generated group that is not finitely presented is the wreath product $\mathbb{Z} \wr \mathbb{Z}$ of the group of integers with itself." But this question is definitely not research-level and not appropriate for MO.

For all $n\geqslant 0$ there exist groups that are of type $F_n$ but not $F_{n+1}$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finiteness_properties_of_groups

In fact, the Higman embedding theorem states that a finitely generated group can be embedded in a finitely presented group if and only if it's generators and relations are recursively enumerable.

@GeoffRobinson I'd rather formulate as: iff, given a finite set $S$ of generators, the set of relations of $S$ is recursively enumerable (in the sense: set of elements $F_S$ that are relations in $G$ is r.e.) — there is no issue of enumerating generators.

@YCor: I did think about that issue, but I think I remembered the  way I was "taught" it (by Higman- taught in the sense that it was a course of lectures that everybody was expected to attend). My memory may have faded, but I agree that what you say is more precise and avoids redundancy.

@GeoffRobinson Ah, possible. The exact wording in the abstract of the famous 1961 Higman paper is "The main theorem of this paper states that a finitely generated group can be embedded in a finitely presented group if and only if it has a recursively enumerable set of defining relations." By the way I always found the papers by Ph. Hall and G. Higman very nicely and carefully written (as opposed to those by G. Baumslag...).

@SamHopkins agreed, it would have to be longer

It is well-known that these exist.
However it is scarcely attributed (e.g., it is not, as of June 10, 2024, in the Wikipedia page Finiteness properties of groups mentioned in the comments). I think this is due to B.H. Neumann in 1937, in the paper "Some remarks on infinite groups", where this is explicitly asserted.

"The corollary suggests the question whether there are any groups which have a finite number of generators but which cannot be defined by a finite set of relations. Such groups exist, as we shall show presently."
[The corollary, Corollary 12, says that being finitely presentable over a given finite set $S$ of generators does not depend on the choice of $S$.]

In this paper, Theorem 13 provides an explicit infinite presentation on 2 generators and asserts that it cannot be defined by a finite set of relators. The presentation is
$$\langle a,b\mid c_n,n\ge 1\rangle;\quad c_n=[a^{-w_n}ba^{w_n},b],\quad w_n=2^{2^n}-1.$$
The proof by B.H. Neumann consists in proving that the $c_n$ are independent relators, by constructing, for each $m$ an explicit finite quotient $G_m$ (an alternating group $A_{w_m}$) in which $c_n$ is a relation iff $n\neq m$.
His second proof is less explicit and consists in constructing (Theorem 14) continuum many non-isomorphic 2-generated groups (using another construction, actually providing residually finite elementary amenable groups).
Back to "Theorem 13", if instead one picks $w_n=n$, one gets a presentation of the wreath product $\mathbf{Z}\wr\mathbf{Z}$; it was shown by G. Baumslag in 1961 (24 years later) that this is also not finitely presentable.
(More generally, any unbounded sequence $w_n$ yields a non-finitely-presentable group, as also follows from the Baumslag method.)
